# Manning F Hunt great, great grandfathers patent

Tags: ownership

In reference to the patent: [US356315][1]

Wondering if patent has expired and the process to claim it.  This was great great grandfathers invention.

Answer (score 0):

This patent has been expired for over 100 years.  It was a 14 year patent with the possibility of a 7 year extension.  There is nothing to claim except your family link to the patent.